# Jenkins failure during trigger

Tags: jenkins

When executing a job I made I got an error before the execute shell had been executed (so this error must come from Jenkins or Git).

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Deploy example.com master branch
Checkout:Deploy example.com master branch / /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Deploy example.com master branch - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@51a745fc
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 133257b4b34f8c0a90bf5ce11c634ebc9587d20d (origin/master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from https://joachimroeleveld:fod4xvo0@bitbucket.org/joachimroeleveld/exofes_profiler.git
Commencing build of Revision 133257b4b34f8c0a90bf5ce11c634ebc9587d20d (origin/master)
Checking out Revision 133257b4b34f8c0a90bf5ce11c634ebc9587d20d (origin/master)
Triggering default
default completed with result FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

What does ' default' mean in this case? Clicking on it results in a page with the links 'Workspace' and 'Recent changes'. Does this error come from a misconfiguration in Git (I use BitBucket for my remote repo's) or Jenkins?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be using multi-configuration job.

If this is the case try to configure "a free-style software project" first. The log will look like the following:

```
Started by an SCM change
Checkout:...
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision ...
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from ...
Commencing build of Revision ...
Checking out Revision ...
[job-name] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7227596484536996852.sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was indeed the problem.

Comment: Outdated links were removed. Basically, they were needed just to simplify problem identification.